# How do I copy all data from one cell to another?

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have been working with the google sheet API, and I need to be able to swap 2 cells with each other. The problem I am running into is that I cannot copy all the data from one cell to another, there is always something missing. The code I have here can copy the data from one cell to another, but the text and notes are missing.

```
UserCredential credential;

using (var stream =
    new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
        System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);


    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        Scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
}

// Create Google Sheets API service.
var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});

// Define request parameters.
String spreadsheetId = "<ID>";

SpreadsheetsResource.GetRequest request =
        service.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId);
request.Ranges = "G16";
request.IncludeGridData = true;

Spreadsheet response = request.Execute();
CellData Cell1 = response.Sheets[0].Data[0].RowData[0].Values;

//get sheet id by sheet name
Spreadsheet spr = service.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId).Execute();
Sheet sh = spr.Sheets[0];
int sheetId = (int)sh.Properties.SheetId;

BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest bussr = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();

//create the update request for cells from the first row
var update = new Request()
{
    RepeatCell = new RepeatCellRequest()
    {
        Range = new GridRange()
        {
            SheetId = sheetId,
            StartColumnIndex = 6,
            StartRowIndex = 13,
            EndColumnIndex = 7,
            EndRowIndex = 14
        },
        Cell = Cell1,
        Fields = "UserEnteredFormat"
    }
};
bussr.Requests = new List<Request>();
bussr.Requests.Add(update);
var bur = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(bussr, spreadsheetId);
bur.Execute();
```

Is there any way to copy over the text/note in the same request?

Answer (score 0):

Your field mask is only allowing format information to be copied. Inside the RepeatCellRequest, try:

```
Fields = "*"
```

See the [field mask documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate#field_masks).